# How can I make a auto scroll for each web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I want to make an auto-scroll down on my WordPress website which was built with elementor. In this video, you see that the auto-scroll code worked every page but I don't want that. I want that for each page(Screenshot). The scroll will be stopping in the red mark section.
How can I do it?

[The page link](https://hf1.graycyan.ca/xyz-xyz-5/)

The auto-scroll will be working just for this page.

Here have a video link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKPEtvGa82UB2kqSYXvXHg1M4r7B4Ecv/view?usp=sharing

The jQuery code:

[image]

The auto-scroll will be working just for this page. and will stop the red mark section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of having a hardcoded scrolltop value, u should make this dynamic by giving the "red marked box" an identifier i.E `id="stop_here"` and in your code u will use the offset relative to the document, e.g:

```
.animate({scrollTop: $('#stop_here').offset().top, ...
```

Comment: I was trying and I can't do that. Can you help me kindly?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help